# In the following CSS, what is the purpose of .reference?

Tags: css, menu

I am exploring some example HTML from codrops. The following CSS is used.
Searching the internet, I can see where others have used span.reference, yet I cannot find an explanation for the purpose of the .reference.

Could anyone enlighten me?

```
span.reference a {
        color: #aaa;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
```

Let me add this link to the actual website for the example at codrops.
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/

Looking through all the html and css, I could find no class by the name of reference anywhere.
I removed all three occurrences of reference in the menu.css code to see what the result would be and the menu system example stopped working properly.

Is there an implied class, or am I missing something really basic here?

Whoops, my bad, I lost track of what I was doing. I put the inline style into a seperate menu.css, then I removed the links that went back to codrops, which you folks had correctly pointed out, there was a class called "reference".
In addition, as I was removing/changing the CSS to see how things were affected, I failed to properly comment out a specific piece, which resulted in the menus being all messed up and when I put it all back it worked so I got hung up on the class "reference" and failed to adequately troubleshoot the person manipulating the hands and fingers.

I apologize for not keeping track of what I had been doing.

"muffled sound of me with my foot in my mouth here"

Comment: ".x" is a simple [Class Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) matching the class "x".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the class on the span element.

```
<span class="reference">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</span>
```